# Cannot call my String Function

Tags: java, function, class, methods

I'm doing a beginner's exercise, and the goal is to create the below output:

> Hello Billy, it's good to meet you!
>
> Hello Jake, it's good to meet you!
>
> Hello Michael, it's good to meet you!

Below is my code:

```
package apollo.exercises.ch03_methods;

public class Ex2_SayMyName {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name1 = "Billy";
        String name2 = "Jake";
        String name3 = "Michael";
    }

    public void SayMyName(String name){
        System.out.println("Hello " + name + ", it's good to meet you!");
    }

    SayMyName(name1);
    SayMyName(name2);
    SayMyName(name3);
}
```

I get errors at `SayMyName(name1);` and the `}` above that line.

For `}`, it says I need to insert another `}` to complete the class body, but isn't it already complete?

For `SayMyName(name1)`, I get "Syntax error, insert "... VariableDeclaratorId" to complete FormalParameterList"

What am I doing wrong? :(

Comment: @DanielStanley - Not at all :).. A couple of *answerers* will learn something (*static context*) here :P

Comment: @TheLostMind Haha that is very true! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the method calls inside your main method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String name1 = "Billy";
    String name2 = "Jake";
    String name3 = "Michael";

    SayMyName(name1);
    SayMyName(name2);
    SayMyName(name3);
}
```

Also, if you don't want an instance of the class `Ex2_SayMyName` when calling `SayMyName` you must make the method static, chage to this:

```
public static void SayMyName(String name)
```

And one last nitpick, respect the java naming conventions and rename your method to start with lowercase. Variables and methods always start with a lowercase letter and classes name start with an uppercase one.

Comment: Thanks for this! I never knew about the naming conventions, so I'll be sure to stick to them.

Answer (score 2):

Put these lines in `main()` method :

```
SayMyName(name1);
SayMyName(name2);
SayMyName(name3);
```

And make `public void SayMyName()` *static* like this :

```
public static void SayMyName(String name){
    System.out.println("Hello " + name + ", it's good to meet you!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `SayMyName` function in class boundary(outside any methods and blocks) which is not possible. In class boundary only **declaration** and **instantiation** can be done.

 Put  `SayMyName` inside main or any other method.

```
public static void main(String... args)
{
    //your code here
    SayMyName(name1);
    SayMyName(name2);
    SayMyName(name3);
 }
```

And change the `SayMyName` method to `static`.
**EDIT-** Class Boundary <- outside any methods and blocks

Comment: that's not quite true, i can put static blocks that print values on screen in that space during class loading

Comment: Yes but that need static variables means name1,2,3 should be static variable.But here op is declaring the variables in main method.Not only static but you can put your code in anonymous block also.

Comment: my point is "only declaration and instantiation can be done" is wrong. I can do this: static {Sytem.out.println("abc");} in the class boundary, it compiles, works and even writes abc to console during class load

Comment: Yes, try out my example

Comment: @MihaiC I know there is concept of static & initializer block. But my point is that in class boundary(outside blocks & method) calling statements are not valid.

Answer (score 0):

What is executed is the `main` method of your class, so, putting the calls to `SayMyName` outside it does not make the desired effect. You need to put the call to your method inside the main method.
Also, the SayMyName has to be static in order for it to be called from the main. You might want to see [this](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/21function/) (about static methods in java)
just like this:

```
package apollo.exercises.ch03_methods;
public class Ex2_SayMyName {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String name1 = "Billy";
    String name2 = "Jake";
    String name3 = "Michael";

    SayMyName(name1);
    SayMyName(name2);
    SayMyName(name3);
}

public static void SayMyName(String name){
    System.out.println("Hello " + name + ", it's good to meet you!");
}
```

Comment: it will not compile saymyname is not static

Comment: @aviad Thanks for the link to static classes! I just want to make sure that I understand. Making a method static is to prevent it from being affected by other elements in the same class right?

Comment: @KennethYong - to declare that this method does not change any class members

Comment: @KennethYong you might also want to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671496/java-when-to-use-static-methods It gives example of when you should use static classes

Answer (score 0):

Call the methods from `main` by moving the following in `main`:

```
SayMyName(name1);
SayMyName(name2);
SayMyName(name3);
```

So that your program looks like this:

```
public class Ex2_SayMyName {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String name1 = "Billy";
    String name2 = "Jake";
    String name3 = "Michael";

    SayMyName(name1);
    SayMyName(name2);
    SayMyName(name3);
}

//note the static in the below line
public static void SayMyName(String name){ 
    System.out.println("Hello " + name + ", it's good to meet you!");
}
}
```

If you want to call your methods directly without making an instance of the class,then you need the `static` keyword in the declaration of the method. This is what I have done in the above program.